# My Discord music bot is not working properly

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to write Music bot for discord but there's a problem.
When I put in a link. It play the music as it should but it didn't play the whole song.
I don't know why it did that so please help me.

Here are my codes:

```
import discord
from discord import voice_client
from discord import guild
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
from discord import FFmpegAudio
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL



bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ">")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("I'm ready for command")

@bot.command()
async def Help(ctx):
    
    emBed = discord.Embed(title = "How to use XXX Bot.", description = "This is every command you can use.", color = 0x03d7fc)
    emBed.add_field(name = ">Help" , value ="To see every command", inline = False)
    emBed.add_field(name = ">play" , value ="Play music", inline = False)
    emBed.add_field(name = ">pause" , value ="Pause music ", inline = False)
    emBed.add_field(name = ">skip" , value ="Stop music", inline = False)
    await ctx.channel.send(embed = emBed)

@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, url):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    voice_client = get(bot.voice_clients, guild = ctx.guild)
    
    if voice_client == None:
        ctx.channel.send("I'm here!")
        await channel.connect()
        voice_client = get(bot.voice_clients, guild = ctx.guild)

    YDL_OPTIONS = {"format" : "bestaudio" , "noplaylist" : True}
    ffmpeg_options = {"options": "-vn", "before_options": "-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5" }

if not voice_client.is_playing():
        with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download = False)
        URL = info["formats"][0]["url"]
        voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(URL))
        voice_client.is_playing()
    else:
        await ctx.channel.send("I'm playing right now")
        return


bot.run("TOKEN")
```

Comment: Try something like `while voice_channel_object.is_playing (): time.sleep (.1)` the `voice_channel_object` is `channel` in your case...

Answer (score 0):

```
    @commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx, *, song=None):
        if await get_mute(ctx.author) != 0:
            await ctx.send("You are blacklisted from the bot")
        else:
            commandd = "play"
            print(f"{ctx.author.name}, {ctx.author.id} used command "+commandd+" used at ")
            print(x)
            print(" ")
            if song is None:
                return await ctx.send("You must include a song to play.")

            if ctx.voice_client is None:
                return await ctx.send("I must be in a voice channel to play a song.")

            # handle song where song isn't url
            if not ("youtube.com/watch?" in song or "https://youtu.be/" in song):
                await ctx.send("Searching for song, this may take a few seconds.")

                result = await self.search_song(1, song, get_url=True)

                if result is None:
                    return await ctx.send("Sorry, I could not find the given song, try using my search command.")

                song = result[0]

            if ctx.voice_client.source is not None:
                queue_len = len(self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id])

                if queue_len < 10:
                    self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id].append(song)
                    return await ctx.send(f"I am currently playing a song, this song has been added to the queue at position: {queue_len+1}.")

                else:
                    return await ctx.send("Sorry, I can only queue up to 10 songs, please wait for the current song to finish.")

            await self.play_song(ctx, song)
            await ctx.send(f"Now playing: {song}")
```

just make it not a cog it needed and get rid of the blacklist